# Get type of System.Linq.Expressions.Expression object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

In my program I have a list of `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` objects.
This list can include different types of a specific `Expression`. For example `BinaryExpression`, `ConditionalExpression` etc. (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).
When reading this list I want to check which specific type of `Expression` it is (`BinaryExpression`, `ConditinalExpression`, etc.).

How do I get the name/type of the derived `Expression` class?

UPDATE

Here the definition of the list of expressions:

```
IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> Expressions { get; }
```

and the code to get the expressions:

```
foreach (var expression in test.Expressions)
{
    var test = expression.GetType().ToString(); //System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[TestObject,System.Object]]
}
```

Comment: have you tried with GetType() ? It will give you the exact runtime type of any object. Should work with Expressions as well

Comment: I tried. It gave me only "System.Linq.Expressions.Expression"

Comment: show an example of your code. also you can use "is" operator. `yourObj is BynaryExpression` - will give you a boolean result

Comment: where does `include.GetType()` comes from ? You should be doing `expression.GetType()` (variable from your foreach code)

Comment: @Gonzalo Sorry. Typo. It is expression. I tried to simplify my code...

Comment: Also please show how do you add elements to Expressions collection. Can you also verify if `is` operator is fine for you ?

Comment: @Gonzalo Unfortunately I cannot use "is" operator since I don't know the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must

```
expression.Body.GetType();
```

What you were looking at is the `Expression<Func<,>>`, what you are interested in is its `.Body`.

Comment: +1, but the OP should note that the type of the `Body` may be a private implementation type, so for some uses testing with `is` is necessary if you want to e.g. identify a `BlockExpression` rather than `ScopeN` (the implementation of `BlockExpression` used when it has more than one child expression, has variables and does not have a type explicitly set to something other than the type of the last child). Just which private implementation types exist and when they are used varies with framework version too, so a strong dependency is inadvisable.

Comment: @JonHanna Yes... You should always use the `is` or the `NodeType` property, because a great piece of expression trees is built upon private subclasses of the various `BinaryExpression`/`UnaryExpression`/...

Comment: For some uses one can also make good use of `var type = GetType(); while (!type.IsPublic){type = type.BaseType;}`.